# how to distribute evenly a set of items in a number of slots?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have 24 slots. If I have 24 items to distribute in the 24 slots I have 1 item per slot. The max slots are 24 and the max items are 24. But If I want to distribute 3 items evenly across the 24 slots, I would like to have one item in slot 6, one in slot 12, and one in slot 18.

Is there in python or pandas a library that could for example distribute 5 items across 24 slots?

In python the slots can be an array:
slots=[]

```
for i in range(0,25):
    slots.append(0)
```

So a distribution of three would look like:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

A distribution of 4 would look like

```
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Can you provide concrete examples as python objects?

Comment: How would you distribute 4 items evenly?

Comment: I added how would I see it in python. Also distributing 4

Comment: Can you give your definition of "*evenly*"? The logic of the 4 items distribution is not clear.

Comment: How is your example of 4 evenly distributed? The number of zeroes in the gaps is 4, 2, 8, 2, 4. Please explain the logic you expect. Gaps of sizes 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 would seem more "even"...

Comment: 3 items > `slot(6,12,18)` is "distribute the space between 3 items evenly across the 24 slots" | "distribute 3 items evenly across the 24 slots" should be `slot(8,16,24)` right?